# Why can't I run this node app on port 3000?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am experimenting with a simple node app...

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I am able to browse to host:1337/ and I see 'Hello World'. However, if I change the port to 3000, I can't load the page.

Comment: Works for me. Best guess is that you're changing it in the string in the `console.log` call, but forgetting to change it in the `listen` call, or something else is using port 3000.

Comment: probably because something else is using 3000. Also, it's good practice to have something like a single variable referring to the port; putting multiple values of the same constant in your code is asking for trouble even in short code snippets. `var ip='127.0.0.1', port=3000` and `listen( ip, port); console.log( 'Server running at http://' + ip + ':' + port)`;

Comment: You got it vogomatix...OK, I feel pretty dumb...I change the port in the console log...not the argument on the listen method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple editing error, not of use to future visitors. *(Lumbee [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547385/157247) saying my first guess in the comment above was indeed correct.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the console log, but not the actual port number in the first argument of the listen method in this line...

```
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

...move along...nothing to see here! ;)

Comment: So, the problem was _"accidentally not changing the port number"_?

Answer (score 1):

You might have another service running at port 3000.

type

netstat -a -b

on the command prompt

it will list all listening ports.. check if 3000 is in use.

Comment: I'd suggest `netstat -abo`, as that also shows the processes' PID, which can come in handy when trying to shut down the related process.